# Can't access ejabberd admin panel using ip address

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I downloaded ejabberd for windows 7. On setup process I done everything correctly. When I start ejabberd from my local system I can access the admin panel using `http://localhost:5280/admin` but if I change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` or `192.168.0.159` (This is my network ip) I can't access admin panel. Is there anything I should configure on `ejabberdctl` or `'ejabberd.yml'` . Please help me.

Comment: How is this related to PHP?

Comment: Sorry. I editted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First Please look in these two office doc link

https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/managing/#web-admin
https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#port-number-ip-address-and-transport-protocol

all you need to do is that set IP address with the port in admin configuration in 'ejabberd.yml'

`hosts:
    - "example.org"
  listen:
    - 
      port: 5280
      module: ejabberd_http
      http_poll: true
    - 
      ip: "0.0.0.0" # << use this ip address
      port: 5282
      module: ejabberd_http
      certfile: "/usr/local/etc/server.pem"
      tls: true
      web_admin: true`

Comment: I found that. Thanks for your answer